# multiproccesing and error The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

I'm having this error when calling my function start and using the multiprocessing module on Python 2.7.8 . I'm using a mac OS 10.9.5.

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. 
You MUST exec(). Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_
COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

Here is the code, under the classe Lattice. My function sansfin is working well and is returning a boolean, it only take as an argument self and an integer to loop on.

```
    def start(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            self.run = True
            p = Process(target=self.sansfin, args=(1000,))
            p.start()
            p.join()

    def stop(self):
        self.run = False
```

I am quite lost with this message. I don't have found anything helpful there and elsewhere. Some are suggesting a bug ...

Comment: the `if __name__ == '__main__':` should not be used inside a class. It allows you to define what is importable and executable in a script

Comment: Thanks
but if I put it in my mai I have the same problem
`def start(L):

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        L.run = True
        p = Process(target=L.sansfin, args=(1000,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
                
def stop(L):
    L.run = False`

Answer (score 9):

To fix this error, you need to explicitly set the `multiprocessing` start method to `spawn` on MacOS. This can be achieved by adding the following immediately below `if __name__ == '__main__'`. For example:

```
import platform, multiprocessing
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

See Also:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psychopy-users/quulKzsQY-Y
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods
3. https://bugs.python.org/issue33725

Answer (score 0):

You should write your script in 2 parts : your function/classes first, and a second part where you create the instances you need and call the functions you want.

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` is here to split these 2 parts. As you put it in your example, I think every process will try to launch itself, and will fork forever, leading to this error.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
class Lattice:
    def __init__(self):
        # init what you need

    def start(self):
        self.run = True
        p = Process(target=self.sansfin, args=(1000,))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def stop(self):
        self.run = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lattice_instance=Lattice()
    lattice_instance.start()
    # wait the time you need
    lattice_instance.stop()
```

Let me know if this help with your issue.

You can also find a very good explanation on the `main` here : [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)